# Convert a multi-dimensional array of objects to single-dimensional array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a multi-dimensional array of objects that is wreaking havoc on Angular's ng-repeat, so I want to convert it to a single-dimensional array. I tried and failed to do so using `forEach`. When I try to use `console.log(newData)` after running the function, it returns an empty array. Am I making it too simple, or did I make a stupid mistake?

```js
//Sample data (allData):

var allData = [{
  "period": 4,
  "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
  "section": [{
    "transferCode": 8675309,
    "details": [{
      "voucherNumber": [34, 22],
      "vendor": "jimmy",
      "description": "blah      ",
      "amount": "t        45,555.00"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "period": 4,
  "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
  "section": [{
    "transferCode": 45576543,
    "details": [{
      "voucherNumber": [22, 33],
      "vendor": "Jonson",
      "description": "trap music      ",
      "amount": "t        12,345.00"
    }]
  }]
}]

//code to push to new array:

var newData = [];

function newArray() {
  allData.forEach(function(top) {
    top.section.forEach(function(mid) {
      mid.details.forEach(function(low) {
        newData.push({
          vendor: low.vendor,
          voucherNumber: low.voucherNumber,
          description: low.description,
          amount: low.amount,
          transferCode: mid.transferCode,
          uploadDate: top.uploadDate,
          period: top.period
        })
      })
    })
  })
  return newData;
}
newArray();
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(newData);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What goes wrong?

Comment: Fair question! Let me edit the question to include that. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @JoshuaSwiss It works fine actually.

Comment: Yeah, it sure does here, just not in my code! I'll play around with it. Thanks for at least confirming I'm not insane.

Comment: The one thing I would suggest would be that `newData` should be declared (or at least re-initialized) *inside* the function. As it is, if you call the function twice, it'll add everything to the end of  the existing array.

Comment: Good point, I'll give that a try @Pointy. Unfortunately, I spoke too soon, as it doesn't work quite as it should. What I'd prefer to get working is to have each occurrence of key/array pairs to get their own array. In the above, the output still has `voucherNumber` returning an array of numbers, whereas each instance should be a single key, single value. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This might help eleviate you from being too literal... Note that the container arrays are skipped (e.g. "section" and "details")

```
// Helper functions
function isArray(obj) {return Array.isArray ? Array.isArray(obj) : Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';}
function isNumber(val) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Number]' && isFinite(val);}


// Flatten object
function flatten(arg, out) {
    out = out || {};
    for (var prop in arg) {
        var val = arg[prop];

        if (isArray(val)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {

                // introspect if the array is just an array of numbers
                var valin = val[i];
                if (isArray(val) && isNumber(valin)) {

                    // just set to the number array and move along.
                    out[prop] = val;
                    break;
                } else {
                    flatten(valin, out);
                }
            }

        // continue looking deeper
        } else if (typeof val == "object") {
            flatten(val, out); 

        // get the value
        } else {
            out[prop] = val; 
        }
    }
    return out;
}


// Put each flattened object into a new data array
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
    data.push(flatten(allData[i]));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, that your presented solution is what you want, so here an interpretation of your data and how to build an redundant data set.

This is the part, where I changed the code for:

```
"details": [{
    "voucherNumber": [34, 22, 23],
    "vendor": ["jimmy", "sam", "jones"],
    "description": ["blah", "blach", "bluch"],
    "amount": [45555, 232, 345346]
}]
```

> Every property in `details` contains an array with the same length (hopefully). I assume, that every index belongs together, like `34, jimmy, blah, 45555`.
>
> The code part for it looks for the keys in `details` and then for the length of every array of the properties. Then it loops over the length and the keys and assign the key/value pairs. After all values for one index are collected, the object is pushed to the result array.

```js
var allData = [{ "period": 4, "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z", "section": [{ "transferCode": 8675309, "details": [{ "voucherNumber": [34, 22, 23], "vendor": ["jimmy", "sam", "jones"], "description": ["blah", "blach", "bluch"], "amount": [45555, 232, 345346] }] }] }, { "period": 4, "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z", "section": [{ "transferCode": 45576543, "details": [{ "voucherNumber": [22, 33], "vendor": ["Jonson", "ronson"], "description": ["trap music", "jesus"], "amount": [12345, 23234] }] }] }];

function newArray(data) {
    var newData = [];
    data.forEach(function (top) {
        top.section.forEach(function (mid) {
            mid.details.forEach(function (low) {
                var keys = Object.keys(low),
                    length = keys.reduce(function (r, a) { return Math.max(r, low[a].length); }, 0),
                    obj, i = 0;
                while (i < length) {
                    obj = {
                        uploadDate: top.uploadDate,
                        period: top.period
                    };
                    keys.forEach(function (k) {
                        obj[k] = low[k][i];
                    });
                    newData.push(obj);
                    i++;
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return newData;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArray(allData), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working with some helpful advice and taking it in a bit of a different direction:

```
var allData = [{
  "period": 4,
  "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
  "section": [{
    "transferCode": 8675309,
    "details": [{
      "voucherNumber": [34, 22, 23],
      "vendor": ["jimmy", "sam", "jones"],
      "description": ["blah", "blach", "bluch"],
      "amount": [45555, 232, 345346]
    }]
  }]
},
{
  "period": 4,
  "uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
  "section": [{
    "transferCode": 45576543,
    "details": [{
      "voucherNumber": [22, 33],
      "vendor": ["Jonson", "ronson"],
      "description": ["trap music", "jesus"],
      "amount": [12345, 23234]
    }]
  }]
}];

var newData = [];

function newArray() {
  allData.forEach(function(top) {
    top.section.forEach(function(mid) {
      mid.details.forEach(function(low) {
        low.vendor.forEach(function(vend){
            low.voucherNumber.forEach(function(vouch) {
                low.description.forEach(function(desc) {
                    low.amount.forEach(function(amt) {
                        newData.push({
                            vendor: vend.vendor,
                            voucherNumber: vouch.voucherNumber,
                            description: desc.description,
                            amount: amt.amount,
                            transferCode: mid.transferCode,
                            uploadDate: top.uploadDate,
                            period: top.period
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  return newData;
}
newArray();
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(newData);
// var test = JSON.stringify(newData);
// console.log(test);
```